# C++ editing a src=" " tag in html

Tags: c++, html, quotations

I am trying to use c++ to edit a large amount of html files. All of it is working except for when i try to edit a src tag. I think it is because of the quotation marks. Here is my code.

```
string strReplace2 = "src=\"\""; //string to replace
```

and

```
strTemp = "src=\"http://localhost/Media/TV Shows/The Big Bang Theory Season 6/" + filename + "\"";
```

When i run the program everything works except that part being written to the file.

Comment: This needs more clarification.

Comment: I don't understand: "`All of it is working except for when i try to edit a src tag`" and "`everything works except that part being written to the file.`" sound like a contradiction. What's the problem?

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the new src string that contains spaces. Spaces should be encoded %20 in URLs. Your question is not clear at all...

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expected to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Don't ever say "everything works" if you're describing code that doesn't work.

Comment: You should probably describe 1. what exactly doesn't work, 2. show the piece of code you suspect isn't quite right. The code should be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the problem (my experience is that I locate my problem creating an SSCCE in the first place, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for replacing things in-between quotes..

```
void replace_between_quotes(std::string &str, const std::string &replacement)
{
    std::size_t pos_f = str.find_first_of("\"");
    std::size_t pos_e = str.find_last_of("\"");

    if (pos_f < pos_e && pos_f != std::string::npos && pos_e != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::size_t len = pos_e - pos_f - 1;
        str.replace(pos_f + 1, len, replacement);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "somefile";
    std::string str = "src=\"http://localhost/Media/TV Shows/The Big Bang Theory Season 6/" + filename + "\"";
    replace_between_quotes(str, filename);
    std::cout<<str;
}
```

Comment: That won't work if there is more than one quotation mark following the first (after `src=`).

Comment: Are you sure about that? You should try it. It finds the very first quotation mark and then the very last one. It does not care about what is between. It does work.

Comment: If you parse `src="hello" tag="world"` which quotation mark do you think `find_last_of` is going to zero in on? Your code is flawed.

Comment: LOL.. my code is flawed? How about your understanding of my code is flawed. I simply said it will replace anything inbetween the FIRST and the LAST quote. That is exactly what it does. http://ideone.com/ywBMeL Works as I said. It only cares what's in-between the first and the very last quote. So yes, the tag attribute is going to get eaten. You said `That won't work if there is more than one quotation mark following the first (after src=)`. Check your understanding again.